# Save image in S3 using gdal

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, gdal

I am working on a project where I need to save an image to S3 using the Gdal python library. 
More specifically, I receive an np array representing that image and I want to send this to an S3 bucket I have.

How am I supposed to do so? I am quiet a newby and I couldn't find an answer in Gdal's website.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you need it to be a GeoTiff or why do you have to use GDAL for this task?
If it is just a numpy array you could also save it using some simpler image library? Or is it a GDAL dataset you need to save to s3?

Comment: It's GDAL dataset I need to save

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

I assume that you have set up your AWS credentials on your machine, since boto3 is using that. If not I think that is out of the scope of this question.

**The simplest is to save the dataset to a file on you disk and then upload it**

I assume that you do not have your dataset on disk? If you already have a tif file with your dataset you can simply ignore  the createcopy part

```
import boto3

# If you only have your dataset in memory, save your dataset in a tif file on disk
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.CreateCopy('path_to_tif_file.tif', your_dataset)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('path_to_tif_file.tif', 'bucket_name', 'path_on_s3.tif')
```

**If you prefer to not save the tif file on disk**

You can also upload a dataset directly to S3, however that is slightly more complicated

```
import boto3

def put_tif_from_gdal_mem_dataset(key, dataset, bucket_name):
    # Load the dataset into the virtual filesystem
    temp_name = '/vsimem/current.tif'
    tiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    tiff_driver.CreateCopy(temp_name, dataset)
    # Read the raw data from the virtual filesystem
    f = gdal.VSIFOpenL(temp_name, 'rb')
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 2)  # seek to end
    size = gdal.VSIFTellL(f)
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(f, 0, 0)  # seek to beginning
    data = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, size, f)
    gdal.VSIFCloseL(f)
    # Upload the raw data to s3
    s3.put_object(Key=key, Bucket=bucket_name, Body=data, ContentLength=size)
    gdal.Unlink(temp_name)

put_tif_from_gdal_mem_dataset('path_on_s3.tif', your_dataset, 'bucket_name')
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing with MRF format but running into errors. Says ERROR 6: Data type not supported by MRF PNG. I'm able to get this workflow working with a tif though. Any ideas?